# Getting a subtype of an object in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype, subtype

I had assumed that the correct way to create a subtype of an object type in Flow would be to use `$Rest`:

```
declare type User = {|
  name?: string,
  age?: number,
  job?: string
|};

declare type UserWithHeight = {|
  ...User,
  height?: number
|};

// This should be UserWithHeight but `name` property should not be allowed
declare type NamelessUserWithHeight = $Rest<UserWithHeight, {| name?: string |}>;

// This should cause an error because `name` shouldn't be allowed,
// but no error is thrown
const user: NamelessUserWithHeight = { name: 'john', height: 10 };
```

However, I don't seem to be getting any error when using a prop that should not be allowed. Here is a [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQVQM4hvAvPAN4A+AUPPAHZQC2IA-AFzxaIwCWVA5gDQXwo3RiyoBXWgCNc-SgCsA9pOat2XbmRIBfANxkyoSLAQp08bLgDqHRAAsAEiA7dbiAsXKUAdD4sxZ8LZOLogq4lK4mrr6APQx8AAqthxYrLYKYhDA8NLmODDWdo7OrjlibgAGNPQV8KgwCugwKGkZWdQKbrlQEBAKAO4gwAbg0HBIaAgAcnQgECBYWH6FDsGlhAAkAEoLiAA8yzarJYi8HtSzKmycPPDaAHx6ZHGJyalY6ZnZYFBiOIJUeC4Bp4aQ-P4IKqzWofNrAKgAci6CB6fUGwzACiobHgEJgLBm9Hmi0ORTWbkIRAu9BYCMUtkRZyCJxYAEYAAzwXRAA).

Comment: If you'll define `name` as required (not optional) property it will work. `name: string`. [Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQATApgY2gQwE6tAC4CeADvgKoDOqOoAvKAN4A+iooAdlgLaoBcoSgRwBLDgHMANG1BZxqAPwCOAV24AjGtPYArWOqWDhY8YmYBfANyIUGbHkKkK1HAHURBABYAJVCPGeBPRMrOwAdBFUWjKefgEEhqoaNGZWNiCgACqeIpSCnrAq0MigmqBRbh4+cYGlKkEABly8DaAkOLBkOMT5hcWcsEFlWNBw8KjItpi4+MRkoAByPKjQqJSUFe5evv61DAAkAEprBAA8m1U78ZIhnMsCQqISoBYAfNaIGfsAomToBN8cB0cIh0LAOEJQCoXAIlrxVusLtsakEGIw7rwBAByPSeDhYm6xXYEAQARgADKArEA)

Comment: Yes, it seems so... Unfortunately for my use case `name` needs to be optional for both `User` and `NamelessUserWithHeight`.

Comment: I've added a bug report - https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5936